# Concept not being recognised

Tags: c++, macos, clang, c++20

I am using the following version of `clang`:

```
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: 
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

I am getting this error with the following code:

```
error: unknown type name 'IntegralType'
template <IntegralType T>
          ^

#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T> concept IntegralType = std::is_integral<T>::value;

template <IntegralType T>
T func(T a)
{
    return a * a;
}

int main(int argv, char* args[])
{
    auto result = func(10);

    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

My `CMake` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(concepts)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(concepts main.cpp)
```

Is something wrong with this syntax, or is this something that AppleClang doesn't yet support, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [cppreference compiler support page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) no version of Apple Clang supports concepts yet.